# Matlab : different data cursor in a same graph

Tags: matlab, cursor

I would like to call 2 different cursor in a same graph, is it possible ? I have 2 graph in a figure (using sublopt). And in the first graph, I have 3 different courb like this :

```
subplot(2,1,1) 
plot(x_new, y2, 'r')
hold on
[hAx,hLine1,hLine2] = plotyy(x_new,y1,x_new,y3);
```

For the moment, I call only one cursor for my figure (so for my 2 graphics, the cursor is the same) like this :

```
dcm_obj = datacursormode(fig);
set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',@cursorcallback);
```

My second problem : when I want to remove the cursor on my coubr, I can't, it stays on the graph.

Thank you in advance,

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

You can add and remove cursors using the context menu interface on the figure itself (by right-clicking).

This can also be done programmatically using `dcm_obj.createDataTip`, `dcm_obj.removeDataCursor` and `dcm_obj.removeAllDataCursors()` but the functionality is not officially documented. There is, however, a good guide to it at http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/controlling-plot-data-tips